# NodeJS readFile On Windows

Tags: node.js, encoding

I keep running in to encoding issues on windows.

```
var content = fs.readFileSync("file.txt", 'utf8').toString();
console.log(content)
```

Where file.txt was created in notepad with the text "123". The output of the above is

```
??1 2 3
```

and not "123" as I would expect. If I read on windows a text file created on a Mac, it works fine. So it is just windows created files causing me the issue.

I've hunted with web with no luck, including this post [node.js readfile error with utf8 encoded file on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356713/node-js-readfile-error-with-utf8-encoded-file-on-windows)

I also experimented with toString('utf8') with no luck.

Later on in code I construct a JSON string using this input, and it ends up as

```
??1\u00002\u00003\u0000�
```

Yuk.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Gary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js readfile error with utf8 encoded file on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356713/node-js-readfile-error-with-utf8-encoded-file-on-windows)

Comment: Check the link from the comment above, because at least I don't experiment this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you've linked to has the answer you want. Notepad is saving the file in a 2-byte encoding with a [byte-order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14403377/4822566).