# nodejs unable to parse date with momentjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, momentjs

I am trying to parse some csv data, however, I am not able to parse date with `momentjs` library.

```
var csv = require('csv-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var moment = require('moment');

const bittrexDateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a";

var count = 0;
fs.createReadStream('orders.csv')
    .pipe(csv({
        headers: ['OrderUuid', 'Exchange', 'Type', 'Quantity', 'Limit', 'CommissionPaid', 'Price', 'Opened', 'Closed']
    }))
    .on('data', function(data) {
        var createDate = moment(data.Opened, bittrexDateFormat);
        console.log(createDate.toDate());
    });
```

And the csv data looks like;

```
OrderUuid,Exchange,Type,Quantity,Limit,CommissionPaid,Price,Opened,Closed
24245deb-134c-4da7-990e-8d22d8fd728c,BTC-STRAT,LIMIT_SELL,77.12739479,0.00087503,0.00016874,0.06749952,12/24/2017 12:09:20 AM,12/24/2017 12:09:21 AM
```

And this the output;

```
0002-01-02T09:00:02.000Z
```

On the other hand, if I directly hardcode the date string I am able to get Date object.

```
var createDate = moment("12/24/2017 12:09:20 AM", bittrexDateFormat);
console.log(createDate.toDate());
```

Another thing I figured out is if I print data in event `.on('data')` it prints encoded string version

```
Row {
  OrderUuid: 'O\u0000r\u0000d\u0000e\u0000r\u0000U\u0000u\u0000i\u0000d\u0000',
  Exchange: '\u0000E\u0000x\u0000c\u0000h\u0000a\u0000n\u0000g\u0000e\u0000',
  Type: '\u0000T\u0000y\u0000p\u0000e\u0000',
  Quantity: '\u0000Q\u0000u\u0000a\u0000n\u0000t\u0000i\u0000t\u0000y\u0000',
  Limit: '\u0000L\u0000i\u0000m\u0000i\u0000t\u0000',
  CommissionPaid: '\u0000C\u0000o\u0000m\u0000m\u0000i\u0000s\u0000s\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000P\u0000a\u0000i\u0000d\u0000',
  Price: '\u0000P\u0000r\u0000i\u0000c\u0000e\u0000',
  Opened: '\u0000O\u0000p\u0000e\u0000n\u0000e\u0000d\u0000',
  Closed: '\u0000C\u0000l\u0000o\u0000s\u0000e\u0000d\u0000\r\u0000' }
Row {
  OrderUuid: '\u00002\u00004\u00002\u00004\u00005\u0000d\u0000e\u0000b\u0000-\u00001\u00003\u00004\u0000c\u0000-\u00004\u0000d\u0000a\u00007\u0000-\u00009\u00009\u00000\u0000e\u0000-\u00008\u0000d\u00002\u00002\u0000d\u00008\u0000f\u0000d\u00007\u00002\u00008\u0000c\u0000',
  Exchange: '\u0000B\u0000T\u0000C\u0000-\u0000S\u0000T\u0000R\u0000A\u0000T\u0000',
  Type: '\u0000L\u0000I\u0000M\u0000I\u0000T\u0000_\u0000S\u0000E\u0000L\u0000L\u0000',
  Quantity: '\u00007\u00007\u0000.\u00001\u00002\u00007\u00003\u00009\u00004\u00007\u00009\u0000',
  Limit: '\u00000\u0000.\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00008\u00007\u00005\u00000\u00003\u0000',
  CommissionPaid: '\u00000\u0000.\u00000\u00000\u00000\u00001\u00006\u00008\u00007\u00004\u0000',
  Price: '\u00000\u0000.\u00000\u00006\u00007\u00004\u00009\u00009\u00005\u00002\u0000',
  Opened: '\u00001\u00002\u0000/\u00002\u00004\u0000/\u00002\u00000\u00001\u00007\u0000 \u00001\u00002\u0000:\u00000\u00009\u0000:\u00002\u00000\u0000 \u0000A\u0000M\u0000',
  Closed: '\u00001\u00002\u0000/\u00002\u00004\u0000/\u00002\u00000\u00001\u00007\u0000 \u00001\u00002\u0000:\u00000\u00009\u0000:\u00002\u00001\u0000 \u0000A\u0000M\u0000' }
```

I am pretty new to nodejs but I don't think the problem occurs from either `momentjs` or `csv-parser` libraries. Instead it should be string format of stream api nodejs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell The expected output is `2017-12-24T08:09:20.000Z`. I will convert it to UTC timezone later.

Comment: log the value of data.Opened and see what is the o/p

Comment: if you are getting format likely this one 0002-01-02T09:00:02.000Z then your date and bittrexDateFormat is not matching

Comment: beside 0002-01-02T09:00:02.000Z date is wrong because first four digit in this will determine your year.

Comment: @krishankTripathi the weird part is I am able to parse date outside createReadStream block. you can also try and verify to get date with "12/24/2017 12:09:20 AM" and format "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a". however in `.on("data")` action it doesn't work. that is why I think there is encoding issue in createReadStream that I am not able to parse it

Comment: @krishankTripathi console.log(data.Opened) gives the correct output which is "12/24/2017 12:09:20 AM" but I am not able to parse the date object by passing `data.Opened` into moment class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code, and it worked just fine.
Try updating your node version or try invoking the function with

```
fs.createReadStream('orders.csv', 'utf16le')
```

the encoding should make the difference...
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Comment: hey rex I tried this before however result was same.

Comment: what's your node version, I'm running on 8.9.3

Comment: could you try nvm (node version manager) and check how it works on 8.9.3

Comment: I'll do that too in 7.4.0...this is a bit strange

Comment: I am upgrading node to the latest version. will let you know once I try it. thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403377/strange-unicode-characters-when-reading-in-file-in-node-js-app

try utf16le

Comment: aaaah finally it worked! :) took so much time to figure it out. but thanks a lot! by the way I accepted your answer but can you put "utf16le" as the correct format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166664/discussion-between-rex-and-quartaela).