# After reading file using fs.readFileSync(), string replace function is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I have a file with name test.txt following data "qwe abc xyz"

And my code is as follows:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8')
    console.log(data)
    data = data.substring(2) //doing this because first two chars are garbage
    console.log(data)
    let data2 = data.replace('abc', 'Decimal');
    console.log(data2)
```

Output of this code:

```
��qwe abc xyz
qwe abc xyz
qwe abc xyz
```

Why isn't my abc getting replaced with Decimal in data2? I have tried with following as well:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8')
    console.log(data)
    data = data.substring(2) //doing this because first two chars are garbage
    console.log(data)
    let data2 = data.replace(/abc/g, 'Decimal');
    console.log(data2)
```

Still it gives the same output. What could be the issue? Can it be related to sync/async?

Comment: Your both code is working properly on my editor

Comment: That's weird. What is the output you are getting?

Comment: i test it in my editor , and it's working too ????. you can debugger after let data = ... . to know how it's work

Comment: ??qwe abc xyz
qwe abc xyz
qwe Decimal xyz above output is copied from my console

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**
As per comments, the file in question was utf-16 little endian. The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404102/11057988) worked.

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf16le');
```

---

Original answer
See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376813/11057988). You have to convert the string to `utf8`.

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8');
data = data.toString('utf8').replace(/^\uFEFF/, '');
```

Comment: This didn't work. I think that answer is related to reading the file with correct encoding whereas my issue is replace command not working. I also checked the encoding of text.txt file and it is 
file -I test.txt
test.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-16le

Comment: you should try logging the string length. It might give you a clue. There are cases where invisible characters are inserted in between all or some characters.

Comment: Also see the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404102/11057988